# How to group result by product id using mysql

Tags: mysql

How to group table by its variants, variant_options and it's sku from different table

my query is:

```
SELECT p.id AS pId, p.name AS pName,
v.name AS vName,
vo.name AS voName,
s.sku, s.price, s.qty
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN variants v ON v.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN variant_options vo ON vo.variant_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN skus s ON s.product_id = p.id
```

and it show like this

```
table:
pId | pName   | vName | voName | sku  | price | qty

1   | adidas  | size  | 42     | AD42 | 100   | 10
1   | adidas  | size  | 43     | AD42 | 100   | 10
1   | adidas  | size  | 42     | AD43 | 100   | 10
1   | adidas  | size  | 43     | AD43 | 100   | 10
```

i want my table to become:

```
table:
pId | pName   | vName | voName | sku  | price | qty

1   | adidas  | size  | 42     | AD42 | 100   | 10
                      | 43     | AD43 | 100   | 10
```

Comment: Try by adding `GROUP BY vo.name, p.id` in the query.

Comment: no result showed by trying it

Comment: #1055 - Expression #9 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'addtocart.v.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: I do not think the error is related to the group by clause. Can you add a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fc37/2

Comment: There is no error and 2 records as result. Where you are getting error? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fc37/15

Comment: it's showing error on regular phpmyadmin

Comment: Can you use `GROUP BY voName, pId` and check

Comment: @Sinto, it's works but, the price on sku table doesn't matches with product_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the GROUP BY for whatever you want.

```
SELECT p.id AS pId, p.name AS pName,
v.name AS vName,
vo.name AS voName,
s.sku, s.price, s.qty
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN variants v ON v.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN variant_options vo ON vo.variant_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN skus s ON s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY v.name, vo.name, s.product_id
```

But sometimes you may choose to only GROUP BY one of them to have less granularity. For example:

```
GROUP BY s.product_id
```